# Desaparece el menu en materialize CSS

Tags: css, materialize

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente proyecto y todo funciona correctamente pero cuando llego a las dimension 2560x1440 hasta donde tengo presente es la dimension mas grande de Computadora consulte esta web para eso: http://www.websitedimensions.com/ , pero lo que no entiendo es porque desaparece el menu, pense que era un error de etiqueta del menu pero no, copie y pege de nuevo la estructura del framework materialize css, alguien sabria porque ?

Mi codigo es este:
(nota uni todo el codigo para que lo vieran completamente, lo tengo separado en su archivos determinado: el html5 con el html5 y el css en su carpeta css)
Soy nuevo con este Framework.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Lovi acabados</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 
  
.nav-wrapper{
  background:#ff7334;
}

.nav-content{
  background:#0D0D0D;
}

.page-footer{
  height:505px;
    background:#000000;

}

.contactoinfo{
  color:#F2F2F2;
}
.tarjetas{
  color:#fff;
}

/*MENU*/


</style>
<body>
  <nav  style="background:#ff7334;" class="lighten-1" role="navigation">
    <div  style="background:#ff7334; class="nav-wrapper container"><a  id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Lovi acados</a>
<ul   id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
        <li><a href="producto1.html">Adoquín</a></li>

           <li><a  href="producto2.html">Azulejo</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto3.html">Barro</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto4.html">Block</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto5.html">Cantera</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto6.html">Esculturas reducidas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto7.html">Fuentes</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto8.html">Granito</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto9.html">Iluminación</a></li>
        <li><a href="producto10.html">Jacuzzi</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto11.html">Ladrillo refractario</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto12.html">Mármol</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto13.html">Piedras decorativas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto15.html">Piso</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto17.html">Sanitarios</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto16.html">Tejas</a></li>

      </ul>
      <a  href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
<!-- Galeria principal -->
  <div id="test1" class="col s12">

 <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img id="active" src="img/logo.png"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Lovi Acabados</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/2.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption left-align">
          <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/3.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption right-align">
          <h3>Right Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/5.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
              <li>
        <img src="img/6.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/7.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/8.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/9.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/10.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/11.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/13.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/13.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/14.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
    <div class="container">
      <br><br>
      <h4 class="header center orange-text">Para vestir tu casa con elegancia y distinción.</h4>
      <div class="row center">
        <h5 class="header col s12 light">Lovi Acabados es la solución.</h5>
      </div>
      <br><br>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="test2" class="col s12">
  <div class="container">
  <h4>Quien Somos</h4>
Lovi Acabados es una compañía dedicada a la venta de materiales y escultura de diferentes tipos de excelente acabado: mármol, granito, cantera, adoquín, cerámica; todo disponible para una presentación adecuada para los hogares.
También vendemos iluminación decorativa, jacuzzis y otros componentes para la decoración de hogar.
     </div>
<div class="container">
  <h4>Nuestra Meta</h4>
Sticky Footer
A sticky footer always stays on the bottom of the page regardless of how little content is on the page. However, this footer will be pushed down if there is a lot of content, so it is different from a fixed footer. Add the following code to your CSS file.

Note: This may cause issues in Internet Explorer which has weak support for flexbox.Sticky Footer
A sticky footer always stays on the bottom of the page regardless of how little content is on the page. However, this footer will be pushed down if there is a lot of content, so it is different from a fixed footer. Add the following code to your CSS file.

Note: This may cause issues in Internet Explorer which has weak support for flexbox.Sticky Footer
A sticky footer always stays on the bottom of the page regardless of how little content is on the page. However, this footer will be pushed down if there is a lot of content, so it is different from a fixed footer. Add the following code to your CSS file.

Note: This may cause issues in Internet Explorer which has weak support for flexbox.      </div>

  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  

<footer style="background:black;" class="page-footer">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col l6 s12">
<center>
<p class="tarjetas">Recibimos todas las tarjetas</p>
<p class="tarjetas">Bienvenidas todas sus tarjetas</p>
<p class="tarjetas">Contamos con terminal movil p/ cobrar a domicilio.</p>
          <img class="responsive-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Credit_card_logos_%282015-12-1816-27-350044%29.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
</center>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">

      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div class="row">
  <form class="col s12">
    <div class="row">


      <div class="container contact">
  <h5>Contacto</h5>
                <p style="color:black;" class=" text-lighten-4">Lovi Acabados: La empresa de cerámica del noroeste.</p>
  <hr>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6">
      <div class="row">
        <form accept="" method="POST" class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
              <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <textarea class="materialize-textarea" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
          <button  style="background:#ff7334;" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit">Enviar
            <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
          </button>
   
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 contact-holder">
      <h6 class="mdi-action-home">Direccion</h6>
      <p >Barrio La Mision Carretera Internacional Km 181 Salida Sur, Magdalena de Kno  C.P 84160</p>
      <h6  class="mdi-hardware-phone-android">Tel:</h6>
      <p >Oficina Tel 6323 - 224515</p>
       <div class="container">
            © 2017 Copyright Lovi acabados
              </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>





  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la solucion, el problema era que yo lo tenia solo para version movil tenia que agregar unas cuantas etiquetas mas:

El codigo funcional:

```html
 <nav style="background:#ff7334;"  class=" lighten-1" role="navigation">

<!--  Menu para version PC -->
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
<li><a  href="producto2.html">Azulejo</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto3.html">Barro</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto4.html">Block</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto5.html">Cantera</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto6.html">Esculturas reducidas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto7.html">Fuentes</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto8.html">Granito</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto9.html">Iluminación</a></li>
        <li><a href="producto10.html">Jacuzzi</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto11.html">Ladrillo refractario</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto12.html">Mármol</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto13.html">Piedras decorativas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto15.html">Piso</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto17.html">Sanitarios</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto16.html">Tejas</a></li>      </ul>
<!-- Menu para version Movil -->
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
<li><a  href="producto2.html">Azulejo</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto3.html">Barro</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto4.html">Block</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto5.html">Cantera</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto6.html">Esculturas reducidas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto7.html">Fuentes</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto8.html">Granito</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto9.html">Iluminación</a></li>
        <li><a href="producto10.html">Jacuzzi</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto11.html">Ladrillo refractario</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto12.html">Mármol</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto13.html">Piedras decorativas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto15.html">Piso</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto17.html">Sanitarios</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto16.html">Tejas</a></li>      </ul>
      <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
```